# Python Pandas: Creating New Variable Based On Sampling Results

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like:

```
>>>df = pd.DataFrame({"V1": range(1, 6)})  
>>>df
   V1
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
```

I would like to partition the data set by average of V1 into two subsets. If the value is greater than the average, the value will be in subset 1, and the rest values will be in subset 2.

For each subset, I want to sample one of them and create a new variable to label them, like "T", And the rest of values will be labeled as "F".

Result should be a dataframe like:

```
   V1  label
0   1     T
1   2     F
2   3     F
3   4     T
4   5     F
```

I've used the codes below, but they didn't work. Is there any solutions to my problem?

```
df['label'] = "F"
df[df['V1'] > df['V1'].mean()].sample(1)['label'] = "T"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to do this, that I can think of is -

```
In [4]: df['label'] = 'F'

In [33]: df.loc[df[df['V1'] > df['V1'].mean()].sample(1).index,'label'] = 'T'

In [34]: df.loc[df[df['V1'] <= df['V1'].mean()].sample(1).index,'label'] = 'T'

In [35]: df
Out[35]:
   V1 label
0   1     T
1   2     F
2   3     F
3   4     F
4   5     T
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df['label'] = pd.Categorical(np.zeros(len(df.index)), categories=[ 'F', 'T'])
df['label'][df.v1 > np.mean(df.v1)] = 'T'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, but what I want to do is not labeling the value which is greater than the average. Instead, I'd like to sample one value from each subset (one is the values are greater the average and the other one's values are lower), and label the two chosen values as "T", and label the rest values as "F".